# nginx proxy_pass change target domain in requests and responses

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, configuration, rewrite, subdomain

My Problem is:

I have a server with an internal domain name `service.internal.example.com` which redirects all clients asking for another domain to its FQDN `https://service.internal.example.com`. This server is not under my control and must continue to be reachable as `service.internal.example.com`.

My job is to setup a proxy that makes this service reachable from the completely separated `external.example.com` DNS domain. (This means the DNS zones does not know about each other and external DNS queries will be answered with *NXDOMAIN* for `*.internal.example.com`)

I have also no control over the DNS domains.

I tried proxy pass, setting the Host header and rewriting but nothing worked so far.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  service.external.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://service.internal.example.com$1 break;

        proxy_pass https://10.1.2.3/; # ip of service.internal.example.com
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header    Host "service.internal.example.com";
        proxy_cookie_domain service.internal.example.com service.external.example.com;  

        sub_filter "service.internal.example.com" "service.external.example.com";
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
    
    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/example.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/example.key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

I would be grateful for some advice.